# Bitcoin-Qt icon not showing in Top Edge Panel (Linux Mint)

Tags: bitcoin-core

I've been using Bitcoin-Qt (now 0.6.2) for two months now with no problems. Now its icon is missing from my top edge panel (Gnome Desktop, Linux Mint 64 bit). How do I get it back? Or is there any other way to open the GUI window?

Restarting the system doesn't help.

I'm new to Linux (used Windows before, but used bitcoin on Linux only).

The bitcoin-qt client is running as I can see the process in System Monitor and also the log file keeps updating. (I don't see any apparent errors in the log.) The bitcoin-qt process starts automatically on system restart.

If I try to start bitcoin-qt, I get the message that it can't obtain a lock and that it is probably already running (which it is). The .lock file (0 bytes) is present in ~/.bitcoin.

What I can do is I can stop the bitcoin-qt process (using System Monitor) and then start it manually and then everything is fine. But after restarting the system, the problem is back.

Any ideas? Should I post more info (which?)? Thanks!

Comment: Others reporting problems with Bitcoin v0.6.2 and Unity on Ubuntu 12.04:

 - http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=81910.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue:

- http://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/1242